# Proving that particular ideal is the kernel of a homomorphism of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> I have the homomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[t]$ with $f(x)=t,f(y)=t^2,f(z)=1$, and I want to prove that $\ker f=(x^2-y,z-1)$.

It is obvious that this ideal is in kernel, but how do I prove other way around, that every polynomial in the kernel is also in the given ideal? (usually in the books there is no explanation, they just use it as a fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]}{\rm{Ker(f)}}\cong \mathbb{R}[t]$$

and $$ \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]}{(x^2-y,z-1)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{(x^2-y)}\cong \mathbb{R}[x,x^2]\cong \mathbb{R}[x]$$

So...

Comment: But how would you put direct proof for your second homomorphism? Using polynomials- that is the part that is bothering me

Comment: Better, but I imagine the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x, y]/(x^{2}-y) \cong \mathbb{R}[x, x^{2}]$ is still not obvious to the OP (of course, I might be wrong here). Perhaps this explicit reasoning will help: $R[x, y] \cong (R[x])[y])$, and $(x^{2}-y) = (y-x^{2})$. Since $y-x^{2}$ is a monic linear polynomial when viewed as a polynomial in $y$, with coefficients in $R[x]$, it is now obvious that $R[x, y]/(x^{2}-y) \cong R[x]$.

Comment: I don't get how the two isomorphisms lead to a solution (unless we are using some non-elementary arguments based on the height of the two ideals). Could someone explain this to me? Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In fact, there are examples of rings $R$ having two prime ideals $P_1\subsetneq P_2$ such that $R/P_1\simeq R/P_2$. (E.g. $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]$, $P_1=(0)$ and $P_2=(X_1)$.)

Comment: @user26857 : I think my justification fails in your case because there are infiinte generators... I do not know how to make this better

Answer (score 3):

In order to prove $\ker f\subseteq(x^2-y,z-1)$ you have to show the following:

> If $p\in\mathbb R[x,y,z]$ is such that $p(t,t^2,1)=0$, then $p\in(x^2-y,z-1)$.

First write $p(x,y,z)=(z-1)q(x,y,z)+r(x,y)$. (We must have $\deg_zr<1$, that's why $r$ is a polynomial only in $x,y$.) Since $p(t,t^2,1)=0$ we get $r(t,t^2)=0$.
Now write $r(x,y)=(y-x^2)s(x,y)+w(x)$. (Analogously, $\deg_yw<1$, so $w$ is a polynomial only in $x$.) Then $r(t,t^2)=0$ implies $w(t)=0$, so $w=0$ and we are done.